# How to push objects to `Store` globally using Emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, websocket

I have a `Message` model with a `value` and `author` properties. I can do this inside the Ember codes (controller, model, views, etc):

```
this.store.push('message', msgObj)
```

However, the following does not work at the Global scope, say putting that inside `<script src="websocket_processor.js">` like:

```
msgObj = {value: 'Hello!', author: 'Jules'}
//I've tried the following but does not work
this.store.push('message', msgObj) //`this` doesn't point to ember
store.push('message', msgObj) //Console error: undefined store
App.Store.push('message', msgObj) //Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {if (!wasApplied) {...
```

I want this to be outside ember because I am using [`websocket-rails`](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) gem from which I use the following function

```
dispatcher.bind('add_message', function(data) { //add_message is just a method param from server
    //Code where I need to use Ember to store say
    this.store.push('message', data)
}
```

I'm stuck with this for hours now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What about storing the data in localStorage? i.e. `localStorage.message = msgObj` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Application initializer to do the job and lookup for store after it has been registered so you can use it in external component.

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function (Application) {
    Application.initializer({
        name: "websocket-rails",
        after: "store",

        initialize: function (container, application) {
            var store = container.lookup('store:main');
            // Now you can inject store to component outside of Ember
        }
    });
});
```